# Raphael paper offset

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

The mouse positions are offset when the paper is moved from the 0,0 position. I think the problem might be in this function:

```
box.view.rect.drag(function(dx,dy,x,y){
        box.x = x;
        box.y = y;
});
```

but I'm not entirely sure. Can anyone help?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zCAL8/1/

If you take out the top div, it works, but with the div in, everything is off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may have found a solution,

you have to remember the position of your box at the moment you press it, and then move your rectangle with the `dx` and `dy` arguments :

```
box.view.rect.mousedown(function(){
    box.initY = box.y;
    box.initX = box.x;
});
box.view.rect.drag(function(dx,dy,x,y, evt){
    box.x = box.initX + dx;
    box.y = box.initY + dy;
});
```